# How to rename ES6 class methods across bundle with a program

Tags: javascript, parsing, uglifyjs, traceur, esprima

I want to obfuscate ES6 class method names. I am using webpack to bundle all my code into a single bundle.js.

Is it possible to find all uses of functions belonging to a certain class and rename them?

Im looking to write a program I can use as part of my build process, not an IDE feature.

How would I do this?

Comment: You're looking for Closure Compiler.

Comment: Im looking to only rename class methods if they are children of a given parent (not all object properties across the bundle like closure advanced does). Im looking for a subset of closure's advanced mode that targets only the code I specify (my application code; not node_modules).